# Is the phrase “totally imaginative” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality

I’ve just come across the phrase in a review, but it doesn’t sound right to me. Can something be “totally imaginative”?

Comment: It's a rather odd collocation (I'm sure ***totally imaginary*** would be far more common), but people use ***totally*** in all sorts of creative ways these days, so I don't think you can really rule this one out.

Comment: Can you provide the context (at the very least the entire sentence this expression appears in)?

Comment: That’s the entire phrase. It’s in a single sentence. It reads: “Totally imaginative. Attention to detail was...”

Comment: @Laurel: Is a *specific* context really necessary? Google Books claims to have about 1450 written instances of the collocation [***totally imaginative***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22totally+imaginative%22) Though that must be set against over 10,000 instances of [***totally imaginary***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22totally+imaginary%22).

Comment: Many people these days, especially the young, use 'totally' to mean merely 'very'.

Comment: Why could something not be *totally imaginative*? What is it about the phrase that strikes you as ungrammatical? (Contrast it with this: *At the moment, my plans are partly imagined and partly realized.*)

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, to me, the word ‘totally’ implies there is a total that can be calculated. However, I feel imagination is something that can’t be quantified, there is no limit or end to imagination. Therefore, I don’t think anything can have complete, or total imagination.

Comment: @Jamie So, when writing about a talking and flying horse that plays on a national cricket team, that's not something that's totally imaginative?

Comment: Has imaginative become a synonym of imaginary and/or imagined while my back was turned?

Comment: FWIW, [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22totally+unimaginative%22) reports about 2000 appearances of ‘‘totally ***un***imaginative’’.

Comment: It would however be helpful to know more about the context in order to understand which meaning of *imaginative* is meant. That word may mean any of the following: 'having or showing creativity or inventiveness' [(here)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/imaginative) ; 'of or relating to images'; 'having a lively imagination'; 'characterized by imagination'; and even simply 'false' [(here)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imaginative).

Comment: An interesting meaning of it is as an antonym of 'based on experience or reality': *"You keep speaking of your book as completely imaginative," the interviewer said. "But nothing is completely imaginative . . . one can only write of what has roots in experience, hidden or open."*  [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=-ZWTsFhJASEC&lpg=PA267&dq=%22Completely%20imaginative%22&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q=%22Completely%20imaginative%22&f=false)  Note that *imaginary* wouldn't work there, as it would imply that the book exists only in the imagination.

Comment: The *OED* also records the usage 'existing only in the imagination; unreal, fancied, imaginary' (with the annotation 'Now *rare*'). An example: *In his planning for the morrow he was dealing with real things, not **imaginative** ones.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that phrase is perfectly fine. Depending on what precisely was meant by the word *imaginative*, the style may or may not need to be informal.

**Discussion**

Below I provide an exhaustive list of meanings of *imaginative* provided in various dictionaries, but it seems to me that the relevant meaning in your case is most likely one of the following four:

1. A product of imagination, as opposed to something that is based on experience and/or reality.
2. Relating to the mental faculty of imagination, especially as opposed to the mental faculty of processing external stimuli or of analytical thought.
3. (Of a person) Having or showing creativity or inventiveness
4. (Of something a person produced) Having the characteristics of something that requires creativity or inventiveness to be produced

I have made these definitions a bit more specialized as compared to those in the dictionaries (which I have reproduced in the last section), so that they are more tailored to how the word is used in the specific examples below.

**OK in formal contexts**

If the relevant meaning is 1. or 2., then *totally* almost certainly means *wholly; entirely; completely* (which is its standard dictionary definition, see e.g. [here](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=totally)). In this case, it is an acceptable construction even in formal contexts. Some examples of similar usage:

> Totally realistic writing would be totally objective; **totally imaginative** writing would be totally subjective. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=yCXXfeSKJnYC&lpg=PA136&dq=%22Totally%20realistic%20writing%20would%20be%20totally%20objective%3B%20totally%20imaginative%20writing%20would%20be%20totally%20subjective.%22&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20realistic%20writing%20would%20be%20totally%20objective;%20totally%20imaginative%20writing%20would%20be%20totally%20subjective.%22&f=false)
>
> Even **totally imaginative** Holocaust literature by those who were not there, who bear no personal losses or relation to the event, continues to be evaluated according to historical accuracy and in the service of testimony to an event whose meanings were negated by meaningless slaughter. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=bnRQeHStHVoC&lpg=PA181&dq=%22Even%20totally%20imaginative%20Holocaust%20literature%20by%20those%20who%20were%20not%20there%2C%20who%20bear%20no%20personal%20losses%20or%20relation%20to%20the%20event%2C%20continues%20to%20be%20evaluated%20according%20to%20histor-%20ical%20accuracy%20and%20in%20the%20service%20of%20testimony%20to%20an%20event%20whose%20meanings%20were%20negated%20by%20meaningless%20slaughter.%22&pg=PA181#v=onepage&q=%22Even%20totally%20imaginative%20Holocaust%20literature%20by%20those%20who%20were%20not%20there,%20who%20bear%20no%20personal%20losses%20or%20relation%20to%20the%20event,%20continues%20to%20be%20evaluated%20according%20to%20histor-%20ical%20accuracy%20and%20in%20the%20service%20of%20testimony%20to%20an%20event%20whose%20meanings%20were%20negated%20by%20meaningless%20slaughter.%22&f=false)
>
> For Malebranche, the human being lives all his life with and through thought, but his thought is almost **totally imaginative.** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=JPhx55N9r64C&lpg=PA331&dq=%22Totally%20imaginative%22&pg=PA331#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20imaginative%22&f=false)

Here the first two use *imaginative* with the meaning 1., while the last one uses it with the meaning 2.

And here are some with *completely imaginative*, which, as I argued, means the same thing. In all of these, the relevant meaning is 1.

> "You keep speaking of your book as **completely imaginative**," the interviewer said. "But nothing is **completely imaginative** . . . one can only write of what has roots in experience, hidden or open." [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=-ZWTsFhJASEC&lpg=PA267&dq=%22Completely%20imaginative%22&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q=%22Completely%20imaginative%22&f=false)
>
> The precipitating factor can be **completely imaginative** and may be psychotic by nature; it also can relate to a real and stressful situation. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qy0vMLYQOPkC&lpg=PA173&dq=%22completely%20imaginative%22&pg=PA173#v=onepage&q=%22completely%20imaginative%22&f=false)
>
> ...a form of representation (the novel structured within history) which is never **completely imaginative** or completely faithful to historical fact, never completely "one or the other,"... [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=OTqwAAAAIAAJ&q=%22completely+imaginative%22&dq=%22completely+imaginative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji6u3-jtLdAhXpCDQIHa_SDVgQ6AEITTAG)

In the first example, note that *completely imaginary* wouldn't work, as it would imply that it is the book exists only in the imagination.

**OK only in informal contexts**

On the other hand, if the relevant meaning of *imaginative* is 3. or 4., then *totally* should probably be interpreted as an **informal** intensifier along the lines of

*informal* Used to emphasize a clause or statement.
*‘I'm sorry, I **totally** didn't mean it’* 
(from [*Oxford Dictionary*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/totally))

True, this says that *totally* is only used to emphasize clauses or statements. However, here are examples of it being used as an intensifier of single adjectives. I should note that such examples are very easy to find; this is not at all an unusual construction:

> He was **totally creative, totally interesting**—therefore a complete misfit. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=6CrZ3J2-7yUC&lpg=PA208&dq=%22Totally%20creative%22&pg=PA208#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20creative%22&f=false)
>
> Lenard Matias, my former head designer and a **totally creative** dresser, looks so chic... [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=RRuWSwVnTmcC&lpg=PT105&dq=%22Totally%20creative%22&pg=PT105#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20creative%22&f=false)
>
> Nail Candy: 50+ ideas for **Totally Cool** Nails [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ktcADQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=%22Totally%20cool%22&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20cool%22&f=false)
>
> **Totally Cool** Journals, Notebooks & Diaries [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=IWt_Po0AQK8C&lpg=PP1&dq=%22Totally%20cool%22&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20cool%22&f=false)
>
> The **Totally Awesome** Book of Useless Information [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=fItbPapWiZQC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22Totally%20awesome%22&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20awesome%22&f=false)
>
> **Totally Awesome** Training Activity Guide Book
>   [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=H4hskgEACAAJ&dq=%22Totally+awesome%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHgp_5pNLdAhWSMn0KHRe_BLAQ6AEIQDAF)
>
> **Totally Wonderful** Miss Plumberry [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=94evAgAACAAJ&dq=%22Totally+wonderful%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMkeKeptLdAhVPHjQIHT6vD7wQ6AEIKTAA)

All of these are informal to at least some degree, but they are completely fine specimens of English.

Here are some likely examples of *totally imaginative* with this informal meaning:

> The result was modern, refreshing, different, and **totally imaginative** playing. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=xdL3u5rSETQC&lpg=PA141&dq=%22Totally%20imaginative%22&pg=PA141#v=onepage&q=%22Totally%20imaginative%22&f=false)
>
> "She was **totally imaginative,** totally futuristic, totally in toto." [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=I5weAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Totally+imaginative%22&dq=%22Totally+imaginative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX4e6MqdLdAhVKHzQIHSCKDfUQ6AEIrwEwGg)
>
> It is something of a relief to come across a totally mimeographed, totally disorganized, **totally imaginative** little magazine. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=-TtVAAAAYAAJ&q=%22it+is+something+of+a+relief+to+come+across+a+totally+mimeographed,+totally+disorganized,+totally+imaginative+little+magazine.%22&dq=%22it+is+something+of+a+relief+to+come+across+a+totally+mimeographed,+totally+disorganized,+totally+imaginative+little+magazine.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKqdGMrNLdAhWwT98KHeBwDdkQ6AEILTAB)
>
> In fact, a **totally imaginative** approach is the only way in which libraries will qualify for some of the included programs. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=UWDVBwj4Dy0C&q=%22Totally+imaginative%22&dq=%22Totally+imaginative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX4e6MqdLdAhVKHzQIHSCKDfUQ6AEItwMwTg)

**The various meanings of *imaginative* as recorded in dictionaries**

[***Merriam-Webster***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imaginative)

**1** a : of, relating to, or characterized by imagination
   b : devoid of truth : false

**2** : given to imagining : having a lively imagination

**3** : of or relating to images especially : showing a command of imagery

[***Oxford Dictionaries***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/imaginative)

Having or showing creativity or inventiveness.
      *making **imaginative** use of computer software*

***OED***

**A.** *adj.*
 **1.** Of, relating to, or concerned in the exercise of imagination as a mental faculty
              *Along with this **imaginative,** inspirational side of the mind goes the capacity... for
               intuition.*
 **2.** Of a person: given to using the imagination; specially characterized by imagination. (a) Full of thoughts, plans, designs, or devices. *Obsolete.*  (b) Full of idle fancies; fanciful.  (c) Having exceptional powers of creative imagination or inventive genius.  (d) Having a lively imagination; willing to use the imagination.
              *Unless a doctor was **imaginative** enough to buck conventional wisdom, ‘treatment’
 
              was hell.*
**3. a.** Existing only in the imagination; unreal, fancied, imaginary. Now *rare.*
              *In his planning for the morrow he was dealing with real things, not **imaginative** ones.*
      **b.** Resulting from the exercise of the imagination; showing a high degree of imagination.
              *In a bold act of **imaginative** literary biography, writer-director Philippe Ramos gives
 
              us a prequel..to Herman Melville's Moby Dick.*

[***American Heritage***](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=imaginative)

**1.** Having a lively imagination, especially a creative imagination.
 
**2.** Created by, indicative of, or characterized by imagination or creativity.
 
**3.** Tending to indulge in the fanciful or in make-believe.
 
**4.** Having no truth; false.

[***Collins***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/imaginative)

If you describe someone or their ideas as imaginative, you are praising them because they are easily able to think of or create new or exciting things. 
        *...hundreds of cooking ideas and **imaginative** recipes.*

in British

**1.** produced by or indicative of a vivid or creative imagination
        *an **imaginative** story*
**2.** having a vivid imagination

in American

**1.** 
having, using, or showing imagination; having great creative powers
**2.** 
given to imagining
**3.** 
of or resulting from imagination
        ***imaginative*** literature

Other dictionaries I looked at don't add any further refinements to the definitions already given above.